Temporarily disable bcache read caching to run a scrub
I use btrfs atop of bcache. It caches small reads and that works great.
When running a scrub of the btrfs however, I'd like those reads to go through to the backing devices because their contents are the ground truth; what I want to verify.
One way to achieve that would be to detach the individual bcache devices from the bcache but doing so necessarily also detaches the bcache state which means it gets lost. It'd have to rebuild the cache every time I run a scrub.
Is it possible to somehow achieve that without losing the cache? I want bcache to keep doing all of its regular state tracking; updating and invalidating the cache. When it comes to utilising the cache though, it should simply read directly from the backing drives and ignore any cached data.

Are you sure that they are cached by bcache?

Yes, I can see the reads. Obviously not all data will be cached as the cache size is limited and bcache attempts to not cache sequential reads but AFAICT, if it's in the cache for whatever reason, it will be read from the cache rather than the disk.

I recently also stumbled over this and it seems to be sufficient to disable caching by writing none to the sysfs files of the backing devices at /sys/fs/bache/BCACHE_UUID/bdev*/cache_mode.
I tested the results using netdata. After disabling the caching mode no more cache hits where counted. So I assume that the cache was disabled after that.
It should be save to do that on a active bcache device.

Does that wipe the cache or does it persist such that enabling it again immediately caches results again?
